# How do I model interaction of three boolean variables for logistic regression when there are empty cells?

Tags: r, regression, model

I collected data to find whether the presence or absence of vision, sound, and touch during a task affected the successful completion of that task. However, there were no samples collected where all three senses were absent. So the dependent variable is boolean success but I have a question about how to model the independent variables in a logistic regression.

My initial analysis used a single categorical variable with seven levels representing each combination of senses (seven because there were no cases where all three senses were absent).

```
summary( glmer( Success ~ Condition + ( 1 | Participant ), family=binomial, data=trials))
```

When I tried to build a model with the Vision, Sound, and Touch as separate variables, the analysis fails. [I believe this is because I have empty cells when including the vision*sound*touch interaction](http://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2010q4/004552.html) because we did not collect results where all senses were absent.

```
summary( glmer( Success ~ Vision + Sound + Touch + Vision*Sound + Vision*Touch + 
                Sound*Touch + Vision*Sound*Touch + ( 1 | Participant ), 
                family=binomial, data=trials))
```

I followed the suggestion linked above to use the `interaction` function to drop the unused factor (all three senses absent). However, this seems to create a variable that looks like my original single categorical variable.

```
senses <- interaction( trials$Vision, trials$Sound, trials$Touch, drop=TRUE )
summary( glmer( Success ~ senses + ( 1 | Participant ), family=binomial, data=trials))
```

As I try to refine this analysis, is there a way to model the senses as separate variables to make the interaction between these variables clearer? That is, to appropriately model the contribution of vision in the `vision`, `vision*sound`, `vision*touch` and `vision*sound*touch` conditions. From the initial analysis, the `vision*sound*touch` interaction is the most interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a series of analyses, with different combinations of the levels. This would, I think, essentially duplicate what a typical analysis would do. You can then compare the results of the different models. So

M1, M2, M3 - each have only two levels for the IV, corresponding to the three dichotomous IVs.
M4, M5, M6 - each have four levels of the IV corresponding to pairs of variables
M7 is your original model.

Comment: I was able to create the seven models you described. However, in this dataset, the `Vision*Sound*Touch` interaction seemed to dominate the M4, M5 and M6 models. That is, the negative impact on the odds of success observed in that condition results in these pair models showing a negative effect when the raw counts are higher than the individual conditions. Thank you for suggesting this analysis, I did learn something from trying the series of models.